# Drastically edited question

Tags: discussion, editing

There was a question that at first was very unclear asking about discarding cards and tagged with magic the gathering. It was gathering close votes for unclear questions and an answer explaining that you don't discard cards during your turn.

After it got closed and a few downvotes it got edited into a question about a phase 10 and discarding in that game. Since it already had an answer and the edited question was drastically different then what was asked and answered shouldn't the edit be reverted and the op directed to make a new post with the question they intended to ask?

[When you lay down cards during your turn, can you change them if you haven't discarded yet?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/39587/when-you-lay-down-cards-during-your-turn-can-you-change-them-if-you-havent-dis)

Answer (score 4):

I think that the question should stay in its current edited state, and that it should be reopened.

That question was closed as "unclear what you're asking", so it is reasonable to assume that edits made by the original poster are intended to clarify the question. The single edit by the OP expanded on the original question and specified a game name without modifying the tags. The simplest explanation for this is that the current question is what they intended from the beginning, and that they simply did not understand how to use the tagging system.

Comment: If there wasn't an answer already posted on the question I would agree. But there is a question on the question and I know a lot of other sites have policies about drastically changing a question after it has already received answers. In this case there should be no issue with reverting the question so the existing answer is not invalidated and having the op ask a new question that is more likely to get better attention then a closed  question with several down votes.

Comment: Answering an unclear question always runs the risk of your answer being invalidated after clarifying edits change how you interpret it. The correct course of action in that case is to not answer at all. We should not hold this question hostage to an incorrect tag just because it was answered. And besides, the existing answer was deleted long before you even asked this meta question, so its existence is really a moot point.

Comment: I understand that but we also should encourage people to ask a more clear question to start with so they don't have to be closed and downvoted before they are fixed enough for a proper answer.

Comment: The primary purpose of closing a question as unclear is to get the asker to clarify it. It may not be the optimal operation of the site, but in this case it worked exactly as intended.

Comment: @JoeW Policies about changing after receiving answers really only make sense when the question was clear and on-topic to start with. In that case, yes, editing into a different question is a bad idea, especially if there are already answers. But if people answered an unclear question based on their guesses, and then the OP fixes it, well, we should be trying to help the OP, not the people who guessed wrong. If they want to preserve their answers, *they* can go ask a new question where their answer fits.